# Bundle java app for mac distribution

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, oracle, ant

I've been trying to create a .app for Mac using Oracle's [appbundler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html). I created a sample javaFX code with just a button displayed on the scene. The following is my Main class.

Main.java

```
package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button root = new Button("Hello world!");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,150,50);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            init(primaryStage);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I run this from eclipse it works. So I created an ant script to bundle the application:

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="builder" default="build-app" basedir=".">

    <property name="src" value="src" />
    <property name="build" value="build" />
    <property name="lib" value="lib" />

    <!-- Target init -->
    <target name="init" description="generate build folder">
        <delete dir="${build}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    </target>


    <!-- Build app -->
    <target name="build-app" depends="init">
        <echo>Building files</echo>
        <javac destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="true">
            <src path="${src}/app" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- Build app -->
    <target name="gen-jar" depends="build-app">
        <jar destfile="${lib}/app.jar" basedir="${build}/app"/>
    </target>


    <!-- BUNDLE APP -->
    <target name="bundle-sample" depends="gen-jar">
        <taskdef name="bundleapp"
            classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
            classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />

        <bundleapp outputdirectory="."
            name="sample"
            displayname="sample"
            identifier="sample"
            mainclassname="app.Main">

            <!-- jdk directory -->
            <runtime dir="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home"/>

            <classpath file="lib/app.jar" />
        </bundleapp>
    </target>

</project>
```

I can now successfully build the ant script by running:

```
ant bundle-sample
```

Although when i run the app I get the following error

```
open sample.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file sample.app
```

Does anybody know what's wrong with the build.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Eclipse anyway I'd advise you to use the e(fx)clipse plugin and then follow this tutorial. It worked for me.

http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/

Good luck
Michael